# php code in wordpress for image uploading

Tags: php, wordpress, image, image-size

Please help with php code:

I have following code what makes only 360x514 images to be uploaded only.
My question is: how can I edit it to make any size uploadable without error message?

```
<?php
$MAXIMUM_FILESIZE = 5 * 1024 * 1024; 
$uploaddir = './uploads/image/large_image/'; 
$file = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['image2']['name']); 
$raw_file_name= $_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'];
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($_FILES['image2']['tmp_name']);
if ($width==360 && $height==514) {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'], $file)) { 
echo "success"; 
} 
else {
echo "error";
}
}else {
echo "size_error";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like @Musa says, remove the check:

```
<?php
$uploaddir = './uploads/image/large_image/'; 
$file = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['image2']['name']); 
$raw_file_name = $_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'];
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'], $file)) { 
    echo "success"; 
} else {
    echo "error";
}
```

Comment: If my answer did solve your problem, consider accepting the answer by clicking on the checkmark on the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($_FILES['image2']['tmp_name']);
if ($width==360 && $height==514) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'], $file)) { 
        echo "success"; 
    } 
else {
    echo "error";
}
```

It is right in your code if you read it... Here it says that it has to be equal to 360x514, just get rid of that IF statement, and just skip to the move_uploaded_file command.